# Can't bind to 'aria-controls' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

Why I get this error on the line:

```
<div
        class="table-section-label mt-0 collapsed"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        href="#docsget_{{ index }}"
        role="button"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="docsget_{{ index }}">
```

Component is:

```
@Input() index: number;
```

Error is:

> Can't bind to 'aria-controls' since it isn't a known property of
> 'div'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7aj1c5?file=src/app/app.component.html) There is no `aria-controls` property on div

```
<div
    class="table-section-label mt-0 collapsed"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    [attr.href]="'#docsget_'+ index "
    role="button"
    aria-expanded="false"
    [attr.aria-controls]="'docsget_'+ index">
```

Comment: same thing for also href there is no property href for div. you can use [attr.href] as a way @Den

Comment: I still get an error: `Can't bind to 'aria-controls' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.` on the line: `[aria-controls]="'bankdetails_' + index"`

Comment: Put your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7aj1c5?file=src/app/app.component.html to this link and fork and share in question